# How to find time of beat (R-event) or RR interval from ECG signal using wfdb toolbox?

Tags: python, signal-processing

I am trying to find the time of beat from the physionet data https://physionet.org/content/prcp/1.0.0/.
I have written the following code for one record 12726:

To read data
`record = wfdb.rdrecord('Postural_data/12726')`

To display data:
`display(record.__dict__)`

The data has 3 signals and I am interested in 'ECG'

```
  record_name': '12726', 
  'n_sig': 3, 'fs': 250, 
  'counter_freq': 24000.0, 
   'sig_len': 825000, 
   'base_time': datetime.time(15, 8, 24), 
   'sig_name': ['ABP', 'ECG', 'Angle'],
```

I want to find RR interval (or time of beat) from the ECG signal data:
`ecg_data = record.p_signal[:,1]`

I am doing:
`rr = wfdb.processing.ann2rr('Postural_data/12726', extension='anI')`

Output:

```
array([87240, 12867, 46962, 12534, 90695, 578, 12171, 37536, 625,
88071, 804, 47876, 65112, 45136, 63753, 12850, 43367, 12540, 51264, 496, 36961, 525])
```

I do not know how to interpret these values and how to get the desired result which is something like below:

```
Beat    rri
0.497   363
0.744   246
1.12    376
1.492   372
1.872   380
2.256   384
2.628   372
```

Column 1 is time of beat and column 2 is RR intervals in mseconds.

```
Beat(i+1) - Beat(i) = rri[i]
```

Thanks for the help.